# What is an example of a groupoid which is not a semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, magma

I know that groupoid refers to an algebraic structure with a binary operation. The only necessary condition is closure.

However, I couldn't find any easy-to-understand example of a groupoid which is not a semigroup. I did come across some examples of (certain type of) matrices but then matrix multiplication is always associative (thus making it a semi-group).

So, could someone please provide me an example of a groupoid which isn't a semigroup?

Comment: You should be careful with the word "groupoid". In the 60s some people used this word to refer to "sets with a binary operation" (possibly non-associative), but these are now called [magmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)). [Groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), on the other hand, are sets (or classes) with a **partially defined** binary operation satisfying group-like properties.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Thanks. I didn't know that. However, I guess in the context of this question: "Give an example of a groupoid which is not a semigroup." I *think* they mean "magma" by "groupoid"?

Comment: Yes, since you're looking for an example of a non-associative binary operation, you're looking for a magma which isn't a semigroup.

Answer (score 6):

These are called [magmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), not groupoids.

The ``midpoint'' operation $s\ast t=\frac{s+t}{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ makes it a magma which is not a semigroup.

Comment: s*t = s-t => Is also a groupoid but not a semi-group. I learned that these are being called magmas now. Thanks!

Comment: (wiki here)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Free_magma] states that `In abstract algebra, a magma, binar[1] or, rarely, *groupoid* is a basic kind of algebraic structure`. If possible can you suggest a nice read on abstract algebra? I am not able to find decent source. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's three different examples.

1. Take an abelian group $(A,+)$ and define a new binary operation $\circ$ on $A$ by $x\circ y=x+(-y)$. This is an example of a *quasigroup*.
2. Take a group $(G,\cdot)$ and define a new binary operation $\triangleleft$ on $G$ by $x\triangleleft y=x\cdot y \cdot x^{-1}$. This is an example of a *quandle*.
3. Take a digraph $(V,A)$ with the property that for any two distinct vertices $v,w\in V$, exactly one of the arcs $vw$ or $wv$ is in $A$. Define a commutative binary operation $\cdot$ on $V$ by $v\cdot v=v$ and $v\cdot w=w$ if and only if $vw\in A$. This is an example of a *tournament*.

A quasigroup is associative if and only if it is a group, a quandle is associative if and only if it is trivial, and a tournament is associative if and only if it is a commutative idempotent semigroup (aka a semilattice).

Answer (score 4):

$( \Bbb Z , -)$

This is a groupoid and not a semi-group.

Answer (score 1):

First, the term 'groupoid' recently rather means primarily a category with invertible arrows, and the term '*magma*' is arising for an algebraic structure with a binary operation.

For a familiar example, consider $\Bbb Z$ (or almost any Abelian group) with the *subtraction*.

Or, define $a*b:=a+b+1$ (or whatever..)

Other examples arise e.g. from finite quasigroups whose multiplication table is a *latin square*: having each element  once in every row and in every column.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b,c$ be distinct members of a three element set and $ab=c=cc $, $bc=a=aa$ and define $ac, bb $ however you like (but in $\{a,b,c\}$.) You have a nonassociative binary operation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{a,b\}$ be a set with two distinct elements.

Define a partial multiplication by $a\times a=a$ and $b\times b=b$ and nothing more (so $a\times b$ and $b\times a$ are not defined).

Then $\{a,b\}$ equipped with this multiplication is a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid), but not a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

I suspect you use another definition of groupoid. If it is what I would call a magma then see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

What about the set $\mathbb{R}^+$ of positive real numbers with exponentiation?

It is not associative:
$$2^{(1^3)}=2\ne 8=(2^1)^3$$
and not commutative:
$$2^3=8\ne 9=3^2.$$
It neither has identity element. Actually, $1$ is a left-absorbing and right identity element:
$${1^n=1\ \forall\,n}\quad\text{and}\quad{n^1=n\ \forall\,n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A non-numerical example of non-associative magma is the Jankenpon game. Let's assume the dyadic operation "*" determines the winner of a match:

(rock * paper) * scissors = paper * scissors = scissors

rock * (paper * scissors) = rock * scissors = rock

Therefore,

(rock * paper) * scissors $\neq$ rock * (paper * scissors).

Incidentally, this magma happens to be commutative and idempotent.